# What is the way to write html code in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im very confused i have to do a project in react and for that i need to implment mapbox but all the instructions are for react How can i write this in my react component. I have this document here which is taken from mapbox library.There is no documentation provided to add map to React.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo: Add custom markers in Mapbox GL JS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .marker {
        background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .mapboxgl-popup {
        max-width: 200px;
      }
      .mapboxgl-popup-content {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJ1bmRoYXRpcjEyIiwiYSI6ImNsNmhqZXFqbDBoc2szY296NmdjYXh3NWgifQ.Nw1KVmbHbDNXOuwoAKDhvw';

      const geojson = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': [-77.032, 38.913]
            },
            'properties': {
              'title': 'Mapbox',
              'description': 'Washington, D.C.'
            }
          },
          {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': [-122.414, 37.776]
            },
            'properties': {
              'title': 'Mapbox',
              'description': 'San Francisco, California'
            }
          }
        ]
      };

      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-96, 37.8],
        zoom: 3
      });

      // add markers to map
      for (const feature of geojson.features) {
        // create a HTML element for each feature
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';

        // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
          .setPopup(
            new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
              .setHTML(
                `<h3>${feature.properties.title}</h3><p>${feature.properties.description}</p>`
              )
          )
          .addTo(map);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to add any of this code in my react app everything just gets messed up .Thanks

Comment: Most of that logic would/could be implemented in a `React.useEffect` hook to instantiate and configure a mapbox instance. The styling is just normal CSS, so however you decide you want to apply it is up to you. Have you already tried to create a React component version of this code? Are you looking for where to get started?

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/

Comment: Always search on npm first. Someone usually have solved your problem for you. In this case there's https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-gl